# htaccess inside the subdirectory redirects to domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using the latest version of Slim Framework and I'm having problems regarding url redirecting.

My main domain is `somedomainname.com`. I have a folder inside it named  `santebarley` so my url is already `somedomainname.com/santebarley`.

The `santebarley` folder is where my slim files reside. So the final route would be `somedomainname.com/santebarley/public` since my `index.php` is in the public folder. The `.htaccess` file is also in the public folder.

I can access the `index.php` though all of my routes redirect to the main domain.

For example, I have a something like this:

```
<a href="/">Click me</a>
```

Instead of going to `somedomainname.com/santebarley/public`, it goes to the domain `robertsoriano.com` or if I have something like

```
<a href="/something">Click me</a>
```

Instead of going to `robertsoriano.com/santebarley/something`, it also goes to `somedomainname.com`.

I really don't know what to edit since this is my first time editing a `.htaccess` file. The `.htaccess` file contains:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I've been using slim before though I want to test it inside a subdirectory. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a .htaccess in site root (in the parent directory of `another/santebarley/`) with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!another/santebarley/public/).*$ another/santebarley/public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I will try this. Actually, I have somedomainname.com/another/santebarley/public so I will put that .htaccess inside another right?

Comment: No in that case use modified answer but still in site root

Comment: Site root you mean inside the santebarley folder?

Comment: No not inside the `santebarley` folder. It should be placed in `DocumentRoot` folder i.e. the parent directory of `another`.

Comment: It works though what I want to happen is instead of for example going somedomain.com/dashboard, I want somedomain.com/another/santebarley/public/dashboard I still want to be inside the public/

Comment: Do you want URL to change as well? If yes then use: `RewriteRule ^(?!another/santebarley/public/).*$ another/santebarley/public/$1 [L,NC,R=302]`